# Difference Between ApplyFilter and SetFilter

Tags: ms-access, vba

What is the difference between the DoCmd.ApplyFilter and DoCmd.SetFilter methods? I looked them up on msdn and I don't see the difference. They even have the same arguements.

Comment: I've been programming in Access VBA for about 8 years and I have never used either one. I use the Form's Filter and FilterOn properties. The DoCmd object isn't necessarily well thought out. It contains many oddities. It's basically an object built to perform the same actions that are built into the Access GUI.

Comment: Someone down-voted this question. Please explain? Sounds like a valid question to me. Both methods have the same parameters and their help pages look very similar.

Comment: 10 minutes of searching and I couldn't find an answer. I agree with @Poweruser that it's a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It (SetFilter) was put in at Version 2010 specifically for tightening the tolerances for the filter (or 'Where' clause) so Access could interact with 1) Web based forms/data and 2) a greater variety of datasources.  For more information, see here:
http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2012/03/19/access-2010-how-to-write-expressions-for-web-queries-forms-and-reports.aspx

They certainly could have done a better job describing the difference, no doubt.  But there is one, however obscure.  All that said, I wonder if anyone tried using (ApplyFilter) in the Web forms with any success.

Craig